# round image using picasso in android

Tags: android

Provide any url's regarding this and xml code for this,it is having errors in  the image view phase

```
package com.example.circularimageview;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.BitmapShader;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.graphics.Color;

import android.graphics.ColorFilter;

import android.graphics.Matrix;

import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.graphics.RectF;

import android.graphics.Shader;

import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;

import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;

import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;

import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();

private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
private int mBitmapWidth;
private int mBitmapHeight;

private float mDrawableRadius;
private float mBorderRadius;

private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

private boolean mReady;
private boolean mSetupPending;
private boolean mBorderOverlay;

public CircleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

   //  mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
    // mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    // mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);

    // a.recycle();

    init();
}

private void init() {
    super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
    mReady = true;

    if (mSetupPending) {
        setup();
        mSetupPending = false;
    }
}

@Override
public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return SCALE_TYPE;
}
```

Comment: What is the error in particular?

Comment: it is not viewing the round image when it is launched

Comment: in circleimageview the code is showing some errors.

Comment: It would help if you could edit those into your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
if (squaredBitmap != source) {
source.recycle();
}

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setShader(shader);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

float r = size / 2f;
canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

squaredBitmap.recycle();
return bitmap;
}

@Override
public String key() {
return "circle";
}
```

After this use picasso bind as below.

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(ImageLink).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ImageView);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: thank you for code i tried but it is not working,it is also having some errors

Comment: i tried solving errors thank you it is working but the image is not viewing properly can u suggest anything for that

Comment: Your welcome. if you feel this answer is useful then please mark as a useful answer so other people will use it too.